# Dynamics CRM 2011 Linq Group Join Method Syntax

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

How can I use group join with method syntax?


I can do a group join with query syntax like this:

```linq
var contAndAcc = from contact in linq.ContactSet
                    join account in linq.AccountSet
                    on contact.ParentCustomerId.Id equals account.AccountId
                    into accountGroup
                    from account in accountGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new{contact = contact, account = account};
```

The compiler converts the query syntax to method syntax, so it must be possible to write the above in method syntax.

These do not work:

```linq
var contAndAcc = linq.ContactSet.GroupJoin(
    linq.AccountSet, // collection to join to
    contact => contact.ParentCustomerId.Id,
    account => account.AccountId, 
    (contact, account) => contact); 

var contAndAcc = linq.ContactSet.GroupJoin(
    linq.AccountSet,
    contact => contact.ParentCustomerId.Id,
    account => account.AccountId,
    (contact, account) => contact)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Select(contact=>contact);

var contAndAcc = linq.ContactSet.GroupJoin(
    linq.AccountSet,
    contact => contact.ParentCustomerId.Id,
    account => account.AccountId,
    (contact, account) => contact)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .SelectMany((contact) => contact);
```

No matter what I try I get this message:
The 'GroupJoin' operation must be followed by a 'SelectMany' 
operation where the collection selector is invoking the 'DefaultIfEmpty' method.

I would also really like to use an IEqualityComparer; will that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Total stab in the dark since I don't do much Linq to CRM, but the QueryExpressions that it gets converted to don't support returning an entire entity.  Try listing every column that you want returned, rather than the entities themselves.